# XML in eclipse not updating?

Tags: android, xml, emulation

I'm using eclipse helios to design a simple android application, however I'm having issues with tidying up the user interface by editing the XML after writing the rest of the application.  However none of the edits to the XML file (I've checked it's the right one) are showing when I send the application to the onscreen emulator.

For example, if I change this segment:
"      "
to
"
      "
and click on the green arrow, the radio button remains "Female".

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen once and once I uninstalled the app from the emulator the next debug session had the right copy of the program in it.

Answer (score 0):

There are known issues with eclipse 3.6 (helios) I suspect that this could be related to one of them.